# how to send row data to another form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display rowdata in another form on clicking a button in a row in Fixed Data Table. 
i don't know how to do it.

```
handleClick: function(){
    window.location.href='/add/app';
},

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="listForm">
      <Table
               rowHeight={50}
               rowsCount={this.state.data.length}
               headerHeight={50}
               width={1000}
               height={500}>
        <Column
          header={<Cell>ID</Cell>}
          cell={props => (<Cell {...props}>{this.state.data[props.rowIndex].id}</Cell>)}
          fixed={true}
          width={50}
        />
        <Column
          header={<Cell>Name</Cell>}
          cell={props => (<Cell {...props}>{this.state.data[props.rowIndex].name}</Cell>)}
          fixed={true}
          width={140}
        />
        <Column
          header={<Cell>Tamil</Cell>}
          cell={props => (<Cell {...props}>{this.state.data[props.rowIndex].mark1}</Cell>)}
          fixed={true}
          width={140}
        />
        <Column
          header={<Cell>Edit</Cell>}
          width={100}
          cell={props => (
          <Cell><button type="button" className="editrow" onClick={this.handleClick}>Edit</button> </Cell>
          )}
        />

      </Table>
      </div>
        );
  }
});
return ListForm;
});
```

In this form i have to display the row data[update student mark form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXeRq.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with react, but could you create hidden inputs for the items you need to send and submit them to your destination page when you click the button?

Comment: Basically, you would have to either pass the state via url properties when you navigate to the other window, or use some place to store the state. If you look at redux, it provides you with such a place, called the store. You could use that, or simulate it yourself to some extent, by at least having a container component responsible for saving application state and passing relevant pieces of it to the children components.